# Visual conviction

Tags: word-choice

I have a question about a translation of an Arabic term: "Ayna'l Yaqin"... meaning conviction based on seeing with the eye. For example, one looks at a table and by what he sees, he is convinced that it's made out of wood.
If one would translate it as "visual conviction", would this be understood correctly or is there a word better fitting for this term?

**Update:**
To make it more clear, there are different levels of being convinced... For example, a scientific conviction, meaning believing in something's existence by study... Like being convinced in the existence of a  country you've never seen before. Second level is a visual conviction... Believing in something's existence by seeing... But this can be misleading, for example, you can see a table and by only looking at it, you can be convinced that the table is made out of wood, while it for example can be made out of plastic with a wooden texture on it... Finally there is a full worthy conviction, meaning your conviction is based on study, seeing, feeling etc... This is the highest level of conviction... I hope this information will help you answer my question.

**Update 2:**

Jonah was cast into the sea and swallowed by a large fish. The sea was stormy, the night was turbulent and dark, and in an allround hopeless condition, he made a supplication which swiftly became his means of salvation. The great mystery of his supplication is this:
In that state all earthly causes that could help him fell silent. For to rescue him under those circumstances, there was a need for an Entity Who could exercise His Command over the fish, the sea, the night and the sky; for the night, the sea and the whale had unified against him. Only an Entity Who could subdue these three simultaneously to His Command would be able to carry him to the shore of salvation. Even if the creation in its entirety had been his servant and helper, it still would not offer him any advantage.
This concludes that causes exert no influence. As Jonah witnessed with a visual conviction that no other than the Causer of causes (meaning God) could be a refuge, his supplication suddenly restrained the night, the sea and the whale.
This is a part of the text... Meaning: in the belly of the whale, Jonah understood through a visual conviction that no one except God could save him… the universal message behind this text is God created causes but humans become heedless and forget that He is the One behind all causes… so the story of Jonah is some kind of wake up call. So with the revelation of Jonah’s story, God wants humans to have a conviction like Jona...in other words: believing like we would believe in something that we see with our eyes… the chosen term to formulate this is “visual conviction”… but is this correct?

Comment: It is made out of wood, as you can see.

Comment: (Based on your 2nd comment) Do you mean Jonah could *see* meaning *realize*, since he could presumably feel and smell also? If you are referring to sight alone, perhaps *visual evidence*? Otherwise perhaps *sensory evidence*.

Comment: "Visual conviction" does not work for me.  You could try asking at SE.law to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

**seeing is believing**

> Idiom—used to say that when something unlikely is witnessed, the truth
> of its occurrence or existence can no longer be doubted
>
> *I didn't think it could happen, but seeing is believing.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seeing%20is%20believing)

> Proverb—You need to see something before you can accept that it really exists
> or occurs.
>
> *There were some people who had given up on it, but now seeing is believing.*
>
> *If seeing is believing, the genuine road user today has to be content with very little space on city roads.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/seeing_is_believing)

Comment: Updated my question with extra information.

Comment: @Bdy It would help us if you could provide an illustrative sentence with a blank ( ______ ) for the word or expression, so we can see how you want to use it.